# node-inspector installation failure: npm ERR! Cannot read property 'pause' of undefined

Tags: node.js, node-inspector

installing node-inspector fails under npm 5.3.0

```
eric@mouni2:~$ sudo npm install -g node-inspector
> v8-profiler@5.7.0 preinstall /usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-inspector/node_modules/v8-profiler
> node -e 'process.exit(0)'

npm ERR! Cannot read property 'pause' of undefined

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/eric/.npm/_logs/2017-09-24T09_34_28_089Z-debug.log
```

This may be related to [npm ERR! Cannot read property 'pause' of undefined --Bluemix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46133316/npm-err-cannot-read-property-pause-of-undefined-bluemix) .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the thread around [npm issue 16677](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/16677#issuecomment-305357667), you can apparently remove `~/.npm`, though `npm cache verify` (no root access necessary) seemed more elegant:

```
eric@mouni2:~$ npm cache verify
Cache verified and compressed (~/.npm/_cacache):
Content verified: 1077 (29065069 bytes)
Content garbage-collected: 15 (201214 bytes)
Index entries: 1442
Finished in 1.482s
eric@mouni2:~$ sudo npm install -g node-inspector
/usr/local/bin/node-inspector -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-inspector/bin/inspector.js
/usr/local/bin/node-debug -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-inspector/bin/node-debug.js
+ node-inspector@1.1.1
updated 1 package in 9.692s
```